# Archive failed in Appcelerator when building for distribution for iOS

Tags: ios, appcelerator-titanium

After having debugged my app using the simulator, I tried "Package -> IOS iTunes Store", but the process always ends with:

```
....
[INFO] :    Invoking xcodebuilder
[ERROR] :   ** ARCHIVE FAILED ***
```

I'am using Axway Appcelerator Studio, build 6.0.0.202005141803 and Titanium SDK 9.2.1 GA.

I tried to delete the "build", "platform" and "i18n" folders, but the problem is still there. What could I do? Is there a way to obtain more information on what went wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: After trying for a lot of time, a friend gave me a good hint: try to build the app using the free version of Titanium. This in turn required to create a new project using Titanium, but in the end it told me that there was a missing dot in the app id with respect to the certificate.

It's a shame, IMHO, that Appcelerator, both Studio and CLI, didn't warn me of this.

Comment: you don't need to create a new project. You can run both version from the CLI: `appc ti` or `ti`. Both are free btw, just one is even open source and doesn't require a free account. You can run it with `-l trace` to get debug output to see more errors. And you can run `ti clean` to clean the project, don't just delete folders unless you know what you are doing. https://github.com/m1ga/from_zero_to_app/blob/master/installation.md#compile-your-app if you use that build script it will print out profile errors. Don't use Studio ;-)

Comment: Thank you miga! I guess you are right, but I can't try it now, since I already resolved the problem the other way.

Comment: was just in case you face it again or someone else will find this problem. At least it is working :)